# How can I install ubuntu 12.04 besides ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, partitioning, system-installation

I have ubuntu 13.10 installed in my laptop (lenovo u430) and I want to have ubuntu 12.04 also (because of graphic drivers). When I try the live cd, it says I have no other OS in my computer and that it'll erase the disk. If I try to resize the partition (lvm) I can only reduce it in 50 MB, but I have around 300 GB of free space. Is there any way around these problems?

Comment: In such a case scenario we cannot help, because **Ubuntu 13.10 is under development**.

Comment: Should I then ask again in two weeks?

Comment: No, this question should not be *removed*. But it would be difficult to find another user that could help about it *right now*.

Comment: Even if we answer you, the procedure could change since 13.10 is not a final revision and it would require of us constant maintenance. If you ask it later we would be able to help since it would be stable system we would talk about.

Comment: The OP here wants to install 12.04, which *is* supported. The fact that the 12.04 installer does not detect 13.10 is probably a bug, however.

Comment: Please help us help you by providing the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo lshw -c disk`. Thank you!